# Move line up/down in Google Docs on Chromebook

Tags: google-docs

I am using Google Docs on my Chromebook and could not find a keyboard shortcut for moving a line up/down.

I use this feature quite often in MS Word to reorder lists or paragraphs.

Now I have to cut and pate each line I would like to move... very tedious.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hope this link helps: [Chromebook keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101?hl=)

Answer (score 2):

Please use Shift+alt alongwith up and down arrow to move the selected line up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to move a bullet point up or down. (Based on [this article](https://blog.jonschneider.com/2022/02/tip-how-to-easily-reorder-bullet-points.html).)